# Section name with fancyhdr in beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to add the name of the section in the fancyhdf foot of a beamer presentation but the following command does not work. I have found some help that suggests the command `\renewcommand{\subsubsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsubsection\ #1}}` but this does not work in my case. I copy/paste all the working code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Class and packages %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ccaption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Author},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=false,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=red,          % color of internal links
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=cyan           % color of external links
}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft}m{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Template %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Page dimension
\paperwidth=16cm
\paperheight=12cm
\textwidth=14cm
\oddsidemargin=-1.5cm
\topmargin=0cm
\headsep=5pt
\marginparsep=0.3cm
\marginparwidth=1cm
\voffset=-2cm
\hoffset=0cm
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\insertframetitle} 

% Header
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}\gdef\stored@title{#1}}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{{\footnotesize\textbf{school}}\hspace{10pt}{\scriptsize departement - \@title}}
\rhead{\scriptsize\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% Footer
\lfoot{\scriptsize\today}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\rfoot{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark }}

% Title frame
\fancypagestyle{fancyonlheadings}{
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{\scriptsize full school name and so on\\
\textbf{Institute name}}
\lfoot{\scriptsize\today}
\rhead{}
}


%%%%%%%%%%%
% Aliases %
%%%%%%%%%%%
\def \be {\begin{equation}}
\def \ee {\end{equation}}
\def \d {\mathrm{d}}
\def \D {\mathrm{D}}
\newcommand{\unit}[1]{ \, \small\mathrm{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Last settings %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
% In beamer, these changes have no effect in preamble
\textheight=10cm
\headheight=0.5cm
\footskip=5pt


%%%%%%%%%
% Title %
%%%%%%%%%
% Title template
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]{
\thispagestyle{fancyonlheadings}
\large{\textbf{SCHOOLNAME}}\\\vspace{10pt}
{\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\Huge\@title}\\\vspace{2cm}
{\Large\insertsubtitle}\\\vfill\vspace{2cm}
{\Large\insertauthor}\par
{\Large\insertinstitute}\\\vspace{0.5cm}
{\small\today}
}

% Title data
\title{Titleeeee}
\subtitle{subtitleeee}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\institute{schoool}

\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Presentation %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{title of the slide}
\lipsum[3]
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}{title of the slide}
\lipsum[3]
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\begin{Large}
\begin{center}
Thanks for your attention!\\ \vspace{10pt}
%\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{fig/steel1.jpg} \\ \vspace{5pt}
Any question?
\end{center}
\end{Large}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

My problem is in the %footer part. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance
philus

Answer (score 2):

If there is no important reason for using `fancyhdr` with `beamer`, I'd suggest to declare headers and footers with `footline` and `headline` `beamertemplates` which is the `beamer's` way.

Following code shows an starting point.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Class and packages %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Author},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=false,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=red,          % color of internal links
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=cyan           % color of external links
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Template %
%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Page dimension
\paperwidth=16cm
\paperheight=12cm
\textwidth=14cm
\oddsidemargin=-1.5cm
\topmargin=0cm
\headsep=5pt
\marginparsep=0.3cm
\marginparwidth=1cm
\voffset=-2cm
\hoffset=0cm
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\insertframetitle} 

% Header
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}\gdef\stored@title{#1}}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\hspace*{1cm}{\footnotesize\textbf{school}}\hspace{10pt}{ departement - \@title}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\thepage\hspace*{1cm}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\hspace*{1cm}\today
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot} \insertsection\hspace*{1cm}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}



%%%%%%%%%%%
% Aliases %
%%%%%%%%%%%
\def \be {\begin{equation}}
\def \ee {\end{equation}}
\def \d {\mathrm{d}}
\def \D {\mathrm{D}}
\newcommand{\unit}[1]{ \, \small\mathrm{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Last settings %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
% In beamer, these changes have no effect in preamble
\textheight=10cm
\headheight=0.5cm
\footskip=5pt


%%%%%%%%%
% Title %
%%%%%%%%%
% Title template
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]{
%\thispagestyle{fancyonlheadings}
\large{\textbf{SCHOOLNAME}}\\\vspace{10pt}
{\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\Huge\@title}\\\vspace{2cm}
{\Large\insertsubtitle}\\\vfill\vspace{2cm}
{\Large\insertauthor}\par
{\Large\insertinstitute}\\\vspace{0.5cm}
{\small\today}
}

% Title data
\title{Titleeeee}
\subtitle{subtitleeee}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\institute{schoool}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Presentation %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{title of the slide}
\lipsum[3]
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}{title of the slide}
\lipsum[3]
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\begin{Large}
\begin{center}
Thanks for your attention!\\ \vspace{10pt}
%\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{fig/steel1.jpg} \\ \vspace{5pt}
Any question?
\end{center}
\end{Large}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]